# Clear submitted form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, button, input

I know this is continuously asked anew, and I've checked out different answers and tried different solutions but to no avail.

I just have to build a form that takes as input the cylinder ray and it height and then find the volume when we click a button.After finding it, shuold be cleared all fields with another button .The function to calculate volume it is working fine, but not the function that clear inputs.

Here is the code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function llogarit() {
      var rreze = parseInt(document.getElementById("val1").value);
      var lartesi = parseInt(document.getElementById("val2").value);
      var rez = document.getElementById("llogarit");
      rez.value = (Math.PI * Math.pow(rreze, 2) * lartesi);
    }

    function fshij() {
      document.getElementById("val1").value.clear();
      document.getElementById("val2").value.clear();
      document.getElementById("llogarit").value.clear();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>Vendos 2 vlera</p>
    <p>rreze
      <input type="text" name="rreze" id="val1" value="2" /></p>
    <p> lartesi
      <input type="text" name="lartesi" id="val2" value="2" /></p>
    <p> Vellimi
      <input type="text" name="vellimi" id="llogarit" value="" /></p>
    <input type="button" onclick="llogarit()" value="llogarit" />
    <input type="reset" value="fshij" onclick="fshij()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

You can reset all form controls in one form with reset method.

```
// <form name="FORM_NAME">

document.forms["FORM_NAME"].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''`

Comment: If a try that it does not calculate neither volume,and also neither with that code that I post, but if a delete that function (fshij) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the follow and add a div tag to the code

```
<div class="yourClass">
<button onclick="cdClear();" class="yourClass">Clear</button>
</div>
```

**Note:** In HTM, you can replace the class with id if you have already coded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cdClear(){var a=document.getElementById("codes");a.value="",a.focus(),</script>
```